# Inconsistent delay in firebase analytics events reaching BigQuery

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I'm seeing unexpected behaviour with timing for Analytics events reaching BigQuery. I'm using the iOS SDK (v6.28.1) and tracking an event called `ecommerce_purchase` which is marked as a conversion event in the console. Logs in Xcode indicate the events are being sent and uploaded.

When I send multiple of these events (e.g. 5 within 3 minutes), only some (e.g 1 - 3) of them will appear in BigQuery intraday table, usually within 15 - 30 minutes. The rest of them will appear the next day, skipping the intraday table completely. If I continue to use the app, I start getting subsequent events in the intraday table, but have to wait for the next day to see the complete picture.

Is there throttling or limits for BigQuery intraday uploads that would mean this is expected behaviour? Has anyone else noticed this?